# VIM: Collapse all the code blocks inside my current block

Tags: vim

In a large PHP application, I would like to collapse all the code blocks inside my current block, but not the current block itself. For instance:

```
if ($something) {

    if ($another) {
        // some code;
    }

    | <--THIS IS MY CURRENT CURSOR POSITION

    if ($yetAnother) {
        // more code;
    }

    if ($stillAnother) {
        // yet more code;
    }

}
```

How can I collapse the three inner `if`s but not the outer `if`?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you already using foldmethod=syntax/indent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing I can come up with is <kbd>zMzv</kbd>. That will close all folds (<kbd>zM</kbd>) and then open just enough folds to view the line your cursor is on (<kbd>zv</kbd>). You can map that to a shorter command if necessary.

It's not exactly what you asked for, since it will close all folds outside of your outer `if` statement as well.

Comment: Thank you. Closing all the folds outside the outer `if` statement is a feature, not a bug! I did have to override the foldmarkers, though.

Answer (score 8):

See if this works:

```
:set foldmethod=marker foldmarker={,} foldlevel=2
```

Comment: I had to `foldlevel=1` but it worked out quite nicely. I never thought of overriding the foldmarker to something so trivial. Does it have drawbacks in practice?

Comment: I've never had much problem with one-character fold markers but then that's anecdotal.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the foldmarkers were in fact giving me trouble. Overriding them as you suggest helps.

Answer (score 2):

If I got the question right, the change in folding described in the statement
is equivalent to the following sequence of actions.

1. Close the current fold (inside which the cursor is located).
2. Recursively close all of the folds inside the just closed one.
3. Open the current fold keeping the inner folds closed.

The mapping

```
:nnoremap <silent> <leader>f m`zcVzCzo``
```

consequently runs the commands corresponding to the aforementioned steps,
saving the cursor position before accomplishing them, and restoring it after.